# Plotly stack button filters

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

I am working on creating a custom graph with plotly and I have two types of filters:
[image]

I need to implement the following:
when two buttons are clicked, the data should be filtered using both filters e.g. State = IN_PROGRESS and LABEL = LAB2

I know how to setup up visibility array for a single button, but I don't know if it is possible in plotly to detect if another button has been clicked so I can include that to calculating the value of 'visibility'. Are there event listeners I can overwrite? Is this possible for scatter figures in plotly? How can I detect if a button is clicked on?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can detect if another button has been clicked – you would probably need to use a callback from `plotly-dash`